# Store all errors in one table

Tags: php, mysql

In order to create an overview of my site, I want to store every action that people make.
So I have this part made:

```
<?php 
if($errors) {
    foreach($errors as $error) {
        $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO deverror (id, ip, page, message, datum) VALUES       (NULL, '".$ip."', 'http://scrshot.com/dev.php', '".$error."', '".$today."')", $connection);
    }
} 
?>
```

Now I have a problem. If I make an error, it makes 3 rows with the error screen:

[image: In separate rows]

How can I put all those "mistakes/errors" in one row, like this?

[image: All in one row]

(Note: Yes, I know I'm using mysql and it's stupid.)

Comment: Use the `implode()` function.

Comment: concatenate the messages.

Comment: A little tip, you can use ip = '$ip' instead of ip = '".$ip."' because you may use variables when you open a string with double quotes (""). Unless you are placing arrays in your query like: ip = '".$ip['value']."'

Comment: MySQL is not stupid...

Comment: @skafandri: It's not. But *using MySQL* is.

Comment: I didnt say MySQL is stupid but it's stupid because im using it instead of MySQLi or PDO OOP etc..

Answer (score 3):

Implode your error array with a newline.

```
<?php 
if($errors){
    $allErrors = implode("\n", $errors);
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO deverror (id, ip, page, message, datum) VALUES (NULL, '".$ip."', 'http://scrshot.com/dev.php', '".$allErrors."', '".$today."')", $connection);
} 
?>
```

Obviously you'd use mysqli/PDO in a live environment.

Comment: have to admit this is superior to my solution (3 less lines), well i'm no php pro; dont hit me :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    if($errors){
        $allErrors = "";
        foreach($errors as $error) {
            $allErrors .= $error."\n";
        }
        $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO deverror (id, ip, page, message, datum) VALUES       (NULL, '".$ip."', 'http://scrshot.com/dev.php', '".$allErrors."', '".$today."')", $connection);
    } 
?>
```

A bit rusty on the php-side here but that should do it, concatenate all errors before passing them to your string.

**BUT BE AWARE THIS COULD BE POTENTIALLY OPEN TO SQL-INJECTIONS.
CONSIDER PREPARED STATEMENTS!**

Comment: We need to program together because you wrote almost the EXACT same script I wrote xp

Comment: How about… not making it open to SQL injection